# Is there a program that would act as a 'local' QoS?

Tags: windows

When I am playing an online game and attempting to download something at the same time, I get high ping in my game. Is there some sort of program I can get that would prioritise game traffic over other (http) traffic? I know that this can be done with QoS on the router level, but I would like a local option. I am running Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand that traffic shaping is generally effective for outgoing traffic only, since you don't control how much data you get from outside, unless it comes through another device (a router) that you control as well, so on it the traffic that goes to your endpoint host is also outgoing, thus can be shaped?